# Who are the X-Men in X-Men Regenesis?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men

In X-Men Regenesis various X-Men are asked to join Logan.  I can recognise some but not all, so want help filling in the gaps.  In order I see:

1. Iceman
2. Betsy, aka ??? (see the first image below)
3. Colossus and Kitty Pryde (second image)
4. Beast
5. ??? and Magneto (third image)
6. ??? and ??? (fourth image)
7. Hope and Idie
8. Paige aka ???, Sam aka ??? and Dani aka ??? (fifth image)
9. ??? (sixth image)

The next divisions are between the students, and then the remainder have their names as captions.

The following are snippets from the comic that I found online to provide an example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you asking about the Regenesis 1 off or the whole line?

Comment: The one-off (post-Schism) I believe.  I didn't know there was a whole line.

Comment: I know this isn't technically a "list question", but looking at these answers below they're pretty much just that: long lists with no obvious rhyme or reason unless you happen to have the comic in hand while you're reading them. Is this really a good use of our Q&A format? Is there a better way of asking this that just doesn't result in long lists of names?

Comment: That's why I uploaded corresponding shots of the comic.  It is now answerable based solely off what is in the question.  I was hoping only someone else who owned the comic would answer the question, because otherwise people would just be throwing darts... exactly like what was seen unfortunately.

Comment: It also looks like adding the images got me exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the images shown the characters are from first to last panel in your statement

1)Iceman
2)Psylocke
3)Colossus and Kitty Pryde
4)Beast
5)Rogue and Magneto
6)Polaris and Havok
7)Oya (Idie Okonkwo)
8)Husk, Cannonball and Mirage
9)Dazzler

The comic then features Rachel Summers, Quentin Quire, X-23, Frenzy, and Gambit, and Toad.

This list does not include the girls hanging outside of Hope's room or anyone in the middle of the baseball field.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what specific picture you are referencing but this is from http://marvel.com/images/gallery/issue/39739/images_from_x-men_regenesis_2011_1/image/880050
Wolverine's team from http://www.comicvine.com/forums/x-men/155/the-who-chose-who-list-x-men-regenesis-spoilers/636628/

Comment: In the actual comic itself, they show Logan asking various X-Men whether they want to join his school.  Because I don't know who's who, I'm looking for specific identification of the X-Men he asked in the comic.

Comment: I took off the that's from the site if that is why I got downvoted. Otherwise I don't understand why my answer was downvoted. There are no pictures that have been added that include anyone from the accepted answer.

Comment: @KevinHowell You're answering who's on the team. dlanod is asking who's being asked in the comics. The two lists aren't the same as some say no or change their mind.