# What side are Rogue and Havok on in Avengers vs X-Men?

Tags: comics, marvel, uncanny-avengers

Marvel has announced a new on-going Avengers/X-Men crossover title called Uncanny Avengers starring:

- Captain America
- Thor
- Scarlet Witch
- Wolverine
- Havok
- Rogue

The first four were all on the side of the Avengers in AvX.  Have we seen which side Rogue and Havok are on?

*(It seems to me to be a pretty pointless "make-up team" if they were all on the Avengers side in the conflict - that's not really making up.)*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rogue, after originally opting to remain neutral as a teacher in Wolverine's school, joins the fight on the side of the X-Men after some Avengers trying to cordon off the school to prevent more mutants joining Cyclops injure some students who try to defend the school (*X-Men Legacy #266*).

[image]

She later switches sides and attempts to assists Ms Marvel escape from Limbo, only to be trapped by Magik (*X-Men Legacy #270)*, so has been on both sides of AvX.

Havok isn't shown on either side.  In [X-Men Regenesis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15003/4056) we see him join Wolverine's school, but he hasn't been present in any of the comics featuring the school during AvX.  It is likely he has remained neutral and continued to protect the school.

Answer (score 2):

**Rogue and Havok have always been X-men.** To be truthful, Rogue started as a member of the [Brotherhood of Evil Mutants against the Avengers](https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q=1046%20b%20street,%20hayward,%20ca&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x808f93d84781dc87:0xc3446630006a9605,1046%20B%20St,%20Hayward,%20CA%2094541&gl=us&ei=zxP6T4bvKMf-2QX7n83sBg&ved=0CAYQ8gEwAA&oi=local_group), (Avengers Annual #10) so I am surprised she would be welcomed even all these years later. Thor and Ms. Marvel should bear a bit of a grudge. Havok has had very limited experience with or against the Avengers, so it should be fairly new to him.

[image: Rogue's first encounter with the Avengers]

If Havok and Rogue are joining this consolidation team it would be a first for both of them to work WITH the Avengers instead of against them.

Comment: Rogue was the most interesting because technically, as part of Wolverine's school (if my memory is right), it seemed like she'd be neutral or on the Avengers side in AvX.